# Attributed strings in UITableViewCells without WebView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

does anyone know if there's a way in with 3.0+ to display attributed strings within a UITableViewCell without using a UIWebView for that? I need to display a string with linked, tappable substrings as the typical detailTextLabel. I wouldn't mind exchanging this UILabel against another type of view, but I think a UIWebView could be just too slow when rendering a table with hundrets of cells. Or does someone have opposite experiences here?

So my question is: what's the best way to achieve mixed strings in a very large table without a great performance hit?

I searched for this almost a whole day now, but I can only find old posts mentioning that there's no attributed string on the iPhone (outdated, as this was pre-3.0) and/or saying that they use a UIWebView for that. But really, I don't think this would perform very well on large tables, would it?

Many, many thanks in advance

Arne

Answer (score 3):

NSAttributedString has valid use only since 3.2.

But you may use [TTStyledTextLabel from three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20/).

Answer (score 0):

**You can create your own view and put it in the cell.**

Have a look at Apple doc related to [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html), I linked the section "A Closer Look at Table-View Cells" which has lots of examples how to modify UITableViewCell.

Comment: Hi,

yes, I know how to customize cells, I'm already doing it, but I don't know which type of subview I could use for that. I don't want to split the text to link sub parts, because it is just one paragraph and I need to link parts of this paragraphs (like hyperlinks, so I can tap a marked word to open a view).